# Write to file when cache expires

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to write to a file the content of cache when Cache expires.

Comment: @Loren - I agree, the question gives almost no relevant details.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using ASP.Net, and you would like to write the content of a particular cached item?

To accomplish this, insert the item into the cache with a callback function specified for when the item is removed.  For example:

```
Cache.Insert("MyText", someTextVariable, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10), 
             TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.High, 
             new CacheItemRemovedCallback(ItemRemoved))


public void ItemRemoved(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
    // write value to file
}
```

If this isn't what you're talking about, you're going to have to give more details in your question, because it's pretty vague.

Comment: Will this work when the cache expires. It looks like this will work when the item is removed from cache. We would like to save the items in cache for 1 hour and then write the contents to a file and followed by resetting the cache item. Please let me know if you need more info.
Thanks
N

Comment: The cache object doesn't expire - the items in it do.  If you insert an item for one hour, the rest of the items don't all expire at the same time.  They each have their own cache time.  The callback "reason" parameter will tell you why it was removed.